# Swift - UITableView doesn't put a UIimage=nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have a problem with my UiTableView.
I have always one row on my tableview (for handling friends)
With this code, it works fine : when I delete a user, it deletes correctly the line on the tableview.
If there is one friend and if I delete it, it modify the text to 'You have no friends ', but the UIimage doesn't go to nil. There is still the image of the Avatar that I have deleted.

How can I fix it and put a nil on my UIImage ?
Thanks !

```
self.MyFriendslist.remove(at: indexPath.row)

if self.MyFriendslist.count == 0 {
let cell = self.MyFriendsTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomFriends") as! MyFriendsTableViewCell

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.MyFriendslist.removeAll()

        cell.MyFriends_AvatarName.text = "You have no friends "
        cell.MyFriends_Avatar.image = nil
        self.MyFriendsTableview.reloadData()
    }
}
else {
    self.MyFriendsTableview.deleteRows(at: [NSIndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0) as IndexPath], with: .fade)

}
```

Comment: you want to show this text in partcular cell or entrie tableview

Comment: I want only to show the text (the text in this code works well), but the image is not displaying nil. It displays the image of the friend that I delete.(the last uiImage). 
cell.MyFriends_Avatar.image = nil  --> not working, it displays the last image.
cell.MyFriends_AvatarName.text = "You have no friends " -->working

Comment: try this  `cell.MyFriends_Avatar.image.isHidden = true`

Comment: Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'isHidden'

Comment: try this `cell.MyFriends_Avatar.isHidden = true`

Comment: That code is only executed when your MyFriendList is empty, so if it is still showing rows, what is your datasource for the tableview?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your `cellForRow` and `numerOfRows` functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments, I have fixed the issue. 
For those who might have this bug, it cames for cellForRow, even if you put whatever logic on a func, some will work with the TableView (the labels) ,but other won't (Image). I fixed it putting a if statement on the cellforRow